# Calling and displaying the results of List memberOf in Microsft Graph

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to display the Office 365 groups a user is a member of in my `ASP.NET MVC` application. In my `UsersController`, I created a Microsoft Graph client and I'm making a request to Graph service to call the MemberOf API. 
The problem is that when I want to display the results from the controller into the view, I don't understand which Microsoft Graph namespace I should call in my model to display the Group name, description and the other responses I get when I call: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf.

I followed Microsoft Graph documentation regarding the List memberOf (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and I included the following code in my UsersController:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyGroups()
        {
            string token = await GetAccessToken();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                // If there's no token in the session, redirect to Home
                return Redirect("/");
            }

            GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }));
            try
            {
                var memberOf = await client.Me.MemberOf.Request()
                                    .GetAsync();

                return View(memberOf);
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new { message = "ERROR retrieving events", debug = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

Then, in my MyGroups view, I am accessing Microsoft.Graph.Group namespace, but I get an error when I run the project.

This is the view code:

```
@model Microsoft.Graph.Group

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My info";
}

<h2>My groups</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            DisplayName
        </th>
        <th>
            GroupTypes
        </th>

    </tr>


    <tr>

        <td>
            @this.Model.DisplayName
        </td>

        <td>
            @this.Model.Description
        </td>

    </tr>
```

This is the error I get on the browser:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Microsoft.Graph.UserMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesPage', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Group'.

Can someone please tell me the right Microsoft Graph namespace I should use to display the results of me/memberOf?

Answer (score 1):

Is your intent to show all groups? If so, your model should probably be `IEnumerable<Microsoft.Graph.Group>`. And your `<tr>` tags contained in a loop.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
      @item.displayName
    </td>
    <td>
      @item.description
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

(Code is from memory so may not compile.)

In the controller, you will need to pass the CurrentPage (or update your code to read all pages):

```
return View(memberOf.CurrentPage);
```

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/collections.md

Answer (score 0):

I managed to display the Groups an user belongs to, with the following code in the UsersController:

```
var memberOf = await client.Me.MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();  
List<Group> groups = memberOf.OfType<Microsoft.Graph.Group>().ToList(); 
return View(groups);
```